# (pandas) how to filter out tweets that contain a question mark?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtering, data-processing

data is in a CSV. trying to filter out any tweets that have a question mark, but none of the code i've tried is working. the code only works when '?' is the only thing in the cell, and not when its a full sentence i.e. 'where is my dog?')

code i've tried:
 `new_df = df[(df.astype(str) != '?').all(axis=1)]`
 `new_df = df['content'].str.contains("\?")`
 `new_df = df[df['content'].str.contains("\?")]`

why aren't any of the above code working? even if the text in my CSV is evaluated as an object, it should now be evaluated as a string?

Comment: @Manakin - you need to add the ~ - for not

Comment: @gtomer ah yes, you can also add `==False` after `str.contains` nice one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df = df[~df['content'].str.contains('\?')]
```